# Intermittently missing pages and posts in WordPress

Tags: 404-error, plugin-w3-total-cache, nginx

Every now and then some of my Wordpress pages (and posts) seems to be missing, I get the 404 page (although the HTTP response code is 200). A couple of hours later the page is back, with no changes in the backend The only thing that I can think of that might cause this is the W3 Total Cache Plugin, but I can't figure out how. Has anyone seen this behaviour before? 3.1 multisite, nginx and w3tc.

Comment: Probably best to look in your apache error logs.

Comment: Nothing in the error logs. in the access log, it looks like an ordinary request with a HTTP 200 response

Answer (score 2):

When you use W3TC with Nginx, it wants to write a `nginx.conf` file into your server root, do you have that file in place, writable by the nginx user?

Also, did you add an `include` directive in your primary nginx config to pull that file in?

For example, in my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dougal.gunters.org` config file, I've got `include /home/dougal/vhost/dougal.gunters.org/nginx.conf` at the end of the `server` block.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your permalinks section and then hit save, if your permalink structure looks ok. This will re save the settings and your pages should reappear.

Comment: I have tried that. Actually you only have to visit the permalinks page to flush the rewrite rules, save is not necessary. But alas, this did not help my problem.